# Javascript In Browser

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, servlets

I wrote a script code and it works fine in eclipse internal browser but if i ran my project in firefox or chorme my popup doesnt appear. What's wrong ?

```
if(clickedButton.name == "sendToApprove"){
    if(document.getElementById("uploadDir").value=='')
    {
        function myFunction() {

            var r = confirm("Talebinizi dosya eksiz gondermek istediginize emin misiniz ?");
            if (r == true) {

                document.main.encoding="multipart/form-data";
                document.main.action="SendToRequestApproveServlet";
            } else {

            }
        }
        myFunction();
    }
    else{
        document.main.encoding="multipart/form-data";
        document.main.action="SendToRequestApproveServlet";
    }

}
```

Comment: any error in the browser console

Comment: nope just popup doesnt appear and no error.And button doesnt send to servlet

Comment: Pop Up Blocker enabled?

Comment: As Arun says, browser console is your friend here.  Turn on script debugging in the console, and put some breakpoints along the code path you expect to be taken in this scenario.  You'll be able to see where exactly things start to go wrong.

Comment: no i completely disabled popup blocker. And lots of users going to use this project is there any way to ask a confirmation thing without disabling pop up blocker ?

Comment: `confirm` is not blocked by pop up blockers (because it isn't a pop up window)

Comment: i solved my problem i have to call value not like this  document.getElementById("uploadDir").value==''
like this document.getElementsByName("uploadDir")[0].value=='' 
thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any error while showing popup then just change the way of displaying popup.
You might be **missing script** to display popup

Try this method to **show popup**

[Jquery popup confirm](http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/)

Comment: I apologize if I miss guide some one but this code worked for me.